# Panda df converting dtype - How to make this faster?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, runtime, apply

I have a panda dataframe with 3 colums with dates in it. They look like this and are not a datetime object yet:

```
In [32]:dfp[["Datum", "Start", "Ende"]]
Out[32]: 
                    Datum              Start                 Ende
0       4.2.2020 00:00:00  2.1.2018 08:00:00  14.12.2021 08:00:00
1       4.2.2020 00:00:00  2.1.2018 08:00:00  14.12.2021 08:00:00
2       4.2.2020 00:00:00  2.1.2018 08:00:00  14.12.2021 08:00:00
3       4.2.2020 00:00:00  2.1.2018 08:00:00  14.12.2021 08:00:00
4       4.2.2020 00:00:00  2.1.2018 08:00:00  14.12.2021 08:00:00
                  ...                ...                  ...
473474  4.8.2020 00:00:00  2.1.2014 08:00:00  29.12.2018 08:00:00
473475  4.8.2020 00:00:00  2.1.2014 08:00:00  29.12.2018 08:00:00
473476  4.8.2020 00:00:00  2.1.2014 08:00:00  29.12.2018 08:00:00
473477  4.8.2020 00:00:00  2.1.2014 08:00:00  29.12.2018 08:00:00
473478  4.8.2020 00:00:00  2.1.2014 08:00:00  29.12.2018 08:00:00

[473479 rows x 3 columns]
```

So I am turning them into datetime objects with this code:

```
dfp["Datum"] = (dfp["Datum"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" 00:00:00", ""))
                ).apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))

dfp["Start"] = (dfp["Start"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" 08:00:00", ""))
                ).apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))

dfp["Ende"] = (dfp["Ende"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" 08:00:00", ""))
                ).apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))
```

After that, pandas is able to recognise these values as datetime objects. However, this takes 12 seconds to run which seems quite a long time compared to all the other pieces of code I have with pandas. Is this a bad way of coding what i did here?

Comment: I'd suggest you ditch `apply` and use pandas to datetime methods instead.

Comment: use [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), e.g. `dfp["Datum"] = pd.to_datetime(dfp["Datum"], dayfirst=True)`.

Comment: I remember that I tried pd.to_datetime, but it didn't work. However it works now, I probably did something wrong last time... Anyway it is much faster now thank you!